# Why am I receiving a typescript error when migrating a Paho MQTT function from Angular 1 to Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mqtt, paho

I am attempting to do several things on connecting to my MQTT broker, I have created an mqtt provider in my ionic 2, angular 2 application, the provider is given below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Paho } from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-greywater',
  templateUrl: 'greywater.html'
})
export class MQTT_Greenchain {
  private _client: Paho.MQTT.Client;
  private options = {
    userName: 'rdjghvoh',
    password: 'w7Ex0VTqZViw',
    timeout: 30,
    useSSL:true,
    onSuccess:this.onConnected,
  };
  private topic: string;
  public displayedMessage: string;
  public mes: Paho.MQTT.Message;
  public constructor() {
    this._client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
      "m20.cloudmqtt.com",
      Number(30775),
      "",
      "peter"
    );
    this._client.onConnectionLost = (responseObject: {errorCode: Number, errorMessage: string}) => {
      console.log('poes');
      console.log(responseObject.errorMessage);
    };

    this._client.onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      this.onMessageArr(message);
      console.log('Message arrived.');
    };
    this.topic = "haha";
    this.displayedMessage = "what I was";
  }
  connectMe() {
    console.log("MQTT OPTIONS: " + this.options);
    this._client.connect(this.options);
  }
  private onConnected(): void {
    console.log('Connected to broker.');
    this._client.subscribe(this.topic);
    this.mes = new Paho.MQTT.Message("-1"); // -1 => Notify
    this.mes.destinationName = this.topic;
    this._client.send(this.mes);
  }
  private onMessageArr(message: Paho.MQTT.Message){
    this.displayedMessage = message.payloadString;
  }
}
```

I have been able to call the following in angular 1 without trouble, and I was able to get everything MQTT-related, working. The function in angular 1 is as follows:

```
function onConnect() {
  sharedUtils.hideLoading();
  console.log("onConnect, CURRENT TOPIC: " + mqttData);
  client.subscribe(mqttData.currentTopic);
}
```

In the above, `mqttData.currentTopic` is merely a string.

The function accepts 1 argument, even though it can accept 2 (an options object).

In angular 2, typescript gives me an error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

Why is it not allowing me to call the function with one argument as in angular 1? If I give it {} as a second argument:

```
this._client.subscribe(this.topic, {});
```

I am given the error that:

```
AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined, Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

This is the error received in the response object parameter, passed to the onConnectionLost callback function.

I am quite certain that my 'this._client' is not undefined since the message 'Connected to broker.' appears in the console, indicating that onConnected, the onSuccess property callback of the connect method was obviously called?

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and reply if it is working fine

```
  this.client.subscribe(this.topic, '');
```